# Finding the matrix of a composition of linear transformations with unequal basis dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $T: \mathcal{P}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2$ definedby $T(p(x)) = p(x+1)$
> Let $S: \mathcal{P}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2$ definedby $S(p(x)) = p(x+1)$
> Let $\mathcal{B} = \{1, x\}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{P}_1$ and
> $\mathcal{C} = \{1, x, x^2\}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{P}_2$

I am asked to determine the matrix of $S\circ T: \mathcal{P}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2$.

I am able to do so, and have determined it to be:

$(S\circ T)_A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

I calculated this by computing the action of $S\circ T$ on the basis $B$.

However, I am confused, as I should be able to calculate the matrices of $T$ and $S$ respectively, and then multiply them together to find the matrix of $S\circ T$.

However the matrix of $S$, which is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ is $3\times3$.

And the matrix of $T$, which is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is $2\times2$.

So obviously I cannot multiply these.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Pay attention to the first correction. Did I do it right? You have not correctly calculated the $T$ and $ST$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the $T$ and $S$ matrices are calculated.
Since $T(1)=1\in\mathcal{P}_2$, $T(x)=1+x\in\mathcal{P}_2$ and $S(1)=1$, $S(x)=1+x$, $S(x^2)=1+2x+x^2$ then
$$
T=
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 1  \\
    0 & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right),\quad
S=
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$
Next
$ST(1)=S(T(1))=S(1)=1$,

$ST(x)=S(T(x))=S(1+x)=S(1)+S(x)=2+x$ and

$$
ST=
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 2  \\
    0 & 1  \\
    0 & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$